# How to properly use two Many-to-one relationships?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How to properly use two Many-to-one relationships?

```
public class Man
    {
        public Man() 
        { 
        }
        [Key]
        public int idMan; { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ManName { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Computer> listComputersBought { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Computer> listComputersSold { get; set; }

    }


public class Computer
    {
        public Computer() 
        {
        }
        [Key]
        public int idComputer{ get; set; }            
        public string ComputerName {get;set;}

        [ForeignKey("ManVendor")]
        public int idManVendor{ get; set; }

        public virtual Man ManVendor { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ManBuyer")]
        public int idManBuyer{ get; set; }

        public virtual Man ManBuyer { get; set; }
    }
```

I'm trying to make two Many-to-one relationships. Doing this, I'm getting the bellow error:

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'idManBuyer' on type 'Project1.Models.Computer' is not valid. The navigation property 'ManBuyer' was not found on the dependent type 'Project1.Models.Computer'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.

How to fix this, please?

Any brilliant idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
public class Man
    {
        public Man() 
        { 
        }
        [Key]
        public int idMan; { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ManName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Computer> listComputersBought { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Computer> listComputersSold { get; set; }

    }


public class Computer
    {
        public Computer() 
        {
        }
        [Key]
        public int idComputer{ get; set; }            
        public string ComputerName {get;set;}

        [ForeignKey("ManBuyer")]
        public int idMan{ get; set; }

        public virtual Man ManBuyer { get; set; }
    }
```